# Problem 5.14 in Isaacs (Algebra a graduate course)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

I am working on the Problem 5.14 in 'Algebra: a graduate course' by Martin Issacs.

> Let $|G|=p(p+1)$, where $p$ is prime. Show that $G$ has either a normal subgroup of order $p$ or one of order $p+1$. HINT: If $n_p(G)>1$, let $x\in G$ with $o(x)\neq 1, p$. Show that $|C_G(x)|=p+1$. Count elements.

I have the following idea: if $G$ does not have a normal $p-$subgroup, then $n_p(G)=p+1$. And $p+1$ $p-$subgroups intersect with each other trivially. There are $(p+1)(p-1)$ order $p$ elements. The remaining $p+1$ elements form a set $Q$ containing $1$ and elements with order not equal to $p$. Take a non-unit element $x$ from $Q$. Since the orbit containing $x$ cannot intersect with the $p$-subgroups, then $|O_x|\leq p$, by the Orbit-Stabilizer, $C_G(x) \geq p+1$. Next I want to show that $C_G(x)$ also lies in $Q$, then $|C_G(x)|\leq p+1$ and we conclude $|C_G(x)|=p+1$. And it is normal since the conjugate won't change the order.

Now the only gap is how to show '$C_G(x)$ also lies in $Q$', i.e. the elements from the $p$-subgroups must conjugate $x$ to another element.

I am not sure if this is the right idea. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Compare it with the solution at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953593/g-pp1-for-p-prime-then-g-has-a-normal-subgroup-of-order-p-or-p1?rq=1). Note that $C_G(P)=N_G(P)$ here.

Comment: Thanks, I think the idea from the other post is that since $n_p(G)=p+1$, meaning $|G:N_G(P)|=p+1$ and $N_G(P)=P$. $P$ cannot lie in $C_G(x)$.